# Do "like" queries with ActiveRecord in Rails 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm doing queries like this in Rails 3.x

```
Speaker.where("name like '%yson%'")
```

but I'd love to avoid the DB specific code. What's the right way to do this?

If there's a way to do this in Rails 2.x too, that would help too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use .matches for it.

```
 > t[:name].matches('%lore').to_sql
 => "\"products\".\"name\" LIKE '%lore'"
```

Actual usage in a query would be:

```
Speaker.where(Speaker.arel_table[:name].matches('%lore'))
```

Comment: Not bad. I guess the percent sign might be common between SQLite, Postgres and Mysql.

Comment: Suggest revising code snippet to read: `Speaker.where(Speaker.arel_table[:name].matches('%yson%'))`

Answer (score 23):

In Rails 3 or greater

```
Speaker.where("name LIKE ?", "%yson%")
```

In Rails 2

```
Speaker.all(:conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "%yson%"])
```

Avoid to directly interpolate strings because the value won't be escaped and you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a search engine like solr or sphinx to create indexes for the columns you would be performing *like* queries on.  *Like* queries always result in a full table scan when you look at the explain plan so you really should almost never use them in a production site.

Comment: I voted this up, but "really should never use them" is a bit strong. If you have a middling number of records, I'd prefer to use a like query than to retrieve and iterate on the middle tier. Obviously if performance gets to be a problem, THEN you should use an index. I think you meant "or" not "of," BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default in Rails, since there are so many DB options (MySQL, Postgresql, MongoDB, CouchDB...), but you can check out gems like [MetaWhere](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where), where you can do things like:

```
Article.where(:title.matches => 'Hello%', :created_at.gt => 3.days.ago)
  => SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE ("articles"."title" LIKE 'Hello%')
     AND ("articles"."created_at" > '2010-04-12 18:39:32.592087')
```

In general though you'll probably have to have some DB specific code, or refactor your code (i.e redefine the .matches operator on symbols in MetaWhere) to work with a different database. Hopefully you won't be changing your database that often, but if you are you should have a centralized location where you define these operators for re-use. Keep in mind that an operator or function defined in one database might not be available in another, in which case having this generalized operation is moot since you won't be able to perform the search anyways.

Comment: Thanks. It's never about changing the DB: it's about having the middle tier NOT be filled with DB-specific code, so you can cut and paste it, and generally forget that the DB exists.

Comment: Then I think the MetaWhere gem is your best bet. It abstracts this and lets you use cool syntax like :title.matches instead of 'title LIKE ?'.