# Multiple like conditions in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to check my records against multiple like statements, what is the best way to do so? i.e.

```
names = ['alice', 'bob', 'mark']
```

I've got table lets say People in my database or (Peoples) so I want to select all people who have names such as those 3 above.

found this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333281/169277

For using like but I couldn't figure out how to pass array of values instead of single values. any ideas?

**UPDATE :**

I need like because people have two names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
names = ['alice', 'bob', 'mark']
Person.where('name REGEXP ?',names.join('|'))
```

While matching like with multiple values on single column you can use [REGEXP](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx) instead of `LIKE`
  this will generate a sql statement with in clause

to check the sql generated just add `.to_sql`

```
Person.where('name REGEXP ?',names.join('|')).to_sql
```

Comment: I need like because someone can have two names and one of those two names is not middle name

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of plugins to that provide for this kind of query, but all you really need is [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel).

You'll need to prepare the query parameters for LIKE using something like this

```
wildcard_names = names.collect { |name| "%#{name}%" } # => ["%alice%","%bob%","%mark%"]
```

Then you'd used the `#matches_any` method of Arel.

```
people_table = People.arel_table
People.where(people_table[:name].matches_any(wildcard_names))
```

As PriteshJ mentioned, add `to_sql` to confirm the query is correct.

Comment: Just a note: on larger data sets the leading wildcard might cause a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.
`Person.where('name SIMILAR TO  ?',"(alice|bob|mark)")` 
 
Advanced matching can also be done 
`Person.where('name SIMILAR TO  ?',"%(alice|bob|mark)%")` 
Above line will also work if name is "jon alice" i.e regex matching.

Refer postgresql documentation : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html